# Binding the control's property in its DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, listview, binding, datatemplate

I have a custom control where I have modified a ListView. I have a DataTemplate which shows each item as an icon of width 128 and a label beneath it.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AeroIconTemplate">
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding Image}" Width="128"
               MaxHeight="128" Margin="0"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black"
                   TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="0" 
                   TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Width="128" MaxHeight="60" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Now I have added a property to the ListView itself called IconSize. This takes an integer between 16 and 256.

I want to bind the `Width`, `MaxHeight` of the `Image` and the `Width` of the `TextBlock` to this property. So whenever the IconSize property is changed the template is adjusted in size. As you can see I am currently binding some stuff to the **data object** (the image source and the label text), but in this case I want to bind to the ListView **control**.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `RelativeSource` for that:

```
... Width="{Binding IconSize,RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}" ...
```

Be sure to define the correct type, since the WPF `ListView` does not have the property `IconSize`. You may need to define your class.

Comment: Thank you! All binding stuff still hasn't fully settled in my brain. :)